# How to remove dashboard item option from Community Portal

Tags: community, partner-portal

I was remove  dashboard item like (recent ,creaed byme and all dashboard ..etc) it is possible or not. i follow community portal admin Navigation Menu --> add menuitem Menu Item

please check below images please any one help me on this

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you want to remove dashboard from navigation menu? Just click click on close (x) from the navigation menu and that should remove it.

Comment: dashboard i need remove only item like recent ,folder and all folder ..etc is it passible or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments -- you need to remove the elements viz., Recent, Folders, etc. from the Dashboard component in your Community.

This is **not** possible with the component that you are using currently. If you verify the component that has been added, it's known as a *DashboardList* component, and that the view you see is the default for that component. There are no properties available for the component where you can show/hide anything specific on the component itself.

---

If you only need the Users to view specific Dashboard, then you can change the navigation to that specific Dashboard instead of your current list view. You can configure it in your menu as below
 [image]